# Need help in JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help.. i want the bin to hide on load and i have a draggable div, so when i drag the div the bin should show and when i leave the div the bin should hide again?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .box{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>

  <script>
  window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = 'none'; };
  function showImg(){
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') { x.style.display = 'block'; }
    else { x.style.display = 'none'; }
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="show" onclick="showImg()" class="box">
    when this div is select and drag the bin should be shown
  </div>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <img src="img/upload.png"/>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem u r facing?

Comment: That is a cute unclear...

Comment: What is *«the bin to hide»* ?

Comment: now the above code is when i drag it is not displaying the bin but when i leave than it display the bin..  so i need help in showing the bin when i drag the div and when i leave the div the bin should hide

Comment: <<the bin to hide>> i did a draggable delete so when i drag a div to the bin the content in the bin will be deleted..

Comment: I do not clearly see any draggable element... And no *«bin»*.

Comment: the bin is the image?

Comment: yes the bin is a image..  the draggable element is on a different code so i m just trying this code out..  the current code will show the image when i click on the div but i need it to show when i drag and when i leave it hide

Comment: i think you need to use ondrag event

Comment: When you refer like this on *«some other code»* on  the very first exploratory questions... I means you question isn't "complete" as per as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/y4t8eo9h/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
            // for show element when start drag    
            document.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
                if (event.target.className == "box") {
                    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
                    x.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
       // for hide element when drag end
        document.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {
            if (event.target.className == "box") {
                var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
                x.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI, you can catch drag events easily in this way:

```
  $("#myDIV").draggable({
     start: function() {

     },
     drag: function() {

     },
     stop: function() {

     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `ondrag` event instead of `click event`.

```
   ondrag="function()"
   ondrop="function()"
   ondragover="function()"
   ondragstart="function()"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .box {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () { document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = 'none'; };
        function showImg() {
            var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
            if (x.style.display === 'none') {
                x.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else { x.style.display = 'none'; }
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#show").draggable();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="show" onclick="showImg()" class="box">
        when this div is select and drag the bin should be shown
    </div>

    <div id="myDIV">
        <img src="~/Images/untitled.gif" />
        @*<img src="img/upload.png" />*@
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```